# Could anyone advise me a good study book for partial differential equations?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, book-recommendation

I want to start learning partial differential equations, but I know that for me the joy of self-study depends a lot on the book/material (I really liked James Stewart's calculus but hated some of my statistical books just by the way they handled the topics and how 'dry' they brought it).

Naturally, I am aware that this is a matter of taste and there is probably no study book that is universally liked. However, I would still love some advice and hear which book you found good on this topic. Preferably something that is more on applications and exercises than on proofs and theories. Also since I am doing it for self-study I really need something for which I can buy a solution manual or for which solutions to exercises can be found online.

Lastly, if it possible it would be nice if it also covers the basics of differential equations as a refresher.

Comment: I recommend checking out Strauss -- it is less rigorous and has much less theory than Evans, but it provides good intuition and it's short. It's a good introduction to PDEs. https://www.amazon.com/Partial-Differential-Equations-Walter-Strauss/dp/0470054565

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend "Partial differential equation" by Lawrence C. Evans. This covers a lot of basic PDE topics. Afterwards you will have a good overlook on this topic.